# как в c++ вывести номер строки двумерного массива если в ней известны идущие подряд числа

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
const int rows = 92;
const int cols = 8;


 int m;
 int i;
 int j;
 int sbd;

int **arr = new int* [rows];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
{
    arr[i] = new int [cols];
}



for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j ++)
    {
        cin >> arr [i][j];
    }
} 


for (int a = 0; a < 1; a ++)
{
for (int b = cols - 1; b >= 0; b --)
{  
    sbd = arr [a][b];
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j ++)
{
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
{
    if (arr [i][j] == sbd)
    {
        m = i + 1;
    }
}
}
}    
cout << m << " ";
}
cout << endl;  

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
  delete[]arr[i];
} 
delete[]arr;
return 0;
}
```

Вводимый массив:

```
1 5 8 6 3 7 2 4 
1 6 8 3 7 4 2 5 
1 7 4 6 8 2 5 3 
1 7 5 8 2 4 6 3 
2 4 6 8 3 1 7 5 
2 5 7 1 3 8 6 4 
2 5 7 4 1 8 6 3 
2 6 1 7 4 8 3 5 
2 6 8 3 1 4 7 5 
2 7 3 6 8 5 1 4 
2 7 5 8 1 4 6 3 
2 8 6 1 3 5 7 4 
3 1 7 5 8 2 4 6 
3 5 2 8 1 7 4 6 
3 5 2 8 6 4 7 1 
3 5 7 1 4 2 8 6 
3 5 8 4 1 7 2 6 
3 6 2 5 8 1 7 4 
3 6 2 7 1 4 8 5 
3 6 2 7 5 1 8 4 
3 6 4 1 8 5 7 2 
3 6 4 2 8 5 7 1 
3 6 8 1 4 7 5 2 
3 6 8 1 5 7 2 4 
3 6 8 2 4 1 7 5 
3 7 2 8 5 1 4 6 
3 7 2 8 6 4 1 5 
3 8 4 7 1 6 2 5 
4 1 5 8 2 7 3 6 
4 1 5 8 6 3 7 2 
4 2 5 8 6 1 3 7 
4 2 7 3 6 8 1 5 
4 2 7 3 6 8 5 1 
4 2 7 5 1 8 6 3 
4 2 8 5 7 1 3 6 
4 2 8 6 1 3 5 7 
4 6 1 5 2 8 3 7 
4 6 8 2 7 1 3 5 
4 6 8 3 1 7 5 2 
4 7 1 8 5 2 6 3 
4 7 3 8 2 5 1 6 
4 7 5 2 6 1 3 8 
4 7 5 3 1 6 8 2 
4 8 1 3 6 2 7 5 
4 8 1 5 7 2 6 3 
4 8 5 3 1 7 2 6 
5 1 4 6 8 2 7 3 
5 1 8 4 2 7 3 6 
5 1 8 6 3 7 2 4 
5 2 4 6 8 3 1 7 
5 2 4 7 3 8 6 1 
5 2 6 1 7 4 8 3 
5 2 8 1 4 7 3 6 
5 3 1 6 8 2 4 7 
5 3 1 7 2 8 6 4 
5 3 8 4 7 1 6 2 
5 7 1 3 8 6 4 2 
5 7 1 4 2 8 6 3 
5 7 2 4 8 1 3 6 
5 7 2 6 3 1 4 8 
5 7 2 6 3 1 8 4 
5 7 4 1 3 8 6 2 
5 8 4 1 3 6 2 7 
5 8 4 1 7 2 6 3 
6 1 5 2 8 3 7 4 
6 2 7 1 3 5 8 4 
6 2 7 1 4 8 5 3 
6 3 1 7 5 8 2 4 
6 3 1 8 4 2 7 5 
6 3 1 8 5 2 4 7 
6 3 5 7 1 4 2 8 
6 3 5 8 1 4 2 7 
6 3 7 2 4 8 1 5 
6 3 7 2 8 5 1 4 
6 3 7 4 1 8 2 5 
6 4 1 5 8 2 7 3 
6 4 2 8 5 7 1 3 
6 4 7 1 3 5 2 8 
6 4 7 1 8 2 5 3 
6 8 2 4 1 7 5 3 
7 1 3 8 6 4 2 5 
7 2 4 1 8 5 3 6 
7 2 6 3 1 4 8 5 
7 3 1 6 8 5 2 4 
7 3 8 2 5 1 6 4 
7 4 2 5 8 1 3 6 
7 4 2 8 6 1 3 5 
7 5 3 1 6 8 2 4 
8 2 4 1 7 5 3 6 
8 2 5 3 1 7 4 6 
8 3 1 6 2 5 7 4 
8 4 1 3 6 2 7 5
```

Найти строку и вывести № которая содержит числа в определенном порядке 4 2 7 3 6 8 5 1, т.е. №33. в программе выше перед удалением массива код с ошибкой, программа выводит № 51. Помогите исправить ошибку.

Comment: слушайте, если уж даете условие, то давайте его правильно, а оно, судя по алгоритму звучит как: Найти строку, которая содержит обратную последовательность чисел первой строки. Я прав?

Comment: Запустил ваш код. Чтобы не мучиться ввел, int cals = 2; int raws = 2; 
Всё работает. Если у вас массив не удаляется, ищите где-то переполнение стэка. Я не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
const int rows = 92;
const int cols = 8;


int m;
int i;
int j;
int sbd;

int **arr = new int* [rows];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
{
arr[i] = new int [cols];
}



for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j ++)
{
    cin >> arr [i][j];
}
} 


int m;
int sbd;
for (int j = 0; j < cols; )
{    
int t = 0;
for(int a = 0; a < 1; a ++)
{
for (int b = cols - 1; b >=0; )
{  
    sbd = arr [a][b];
for (int i = t; i < rows; )
{ 
    if (arr [i][j] != sbd)
    {
        i ++;
    }
    else if (arr [i][j] == sbd)
    {
        t = i;
        j ++;
        b --;
        if (b == 0)
        {
            m = i;
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
}
}
cout << m + 1;
cout << endl; 

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   delete[]arr[i];
} 
delete[]arr;
return 0;
}
```

Ошибка исправлена)))

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема в логике цикла:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
  for (int b = cols - 1; b >= 0; b--) {
    sbd = arr[a][b];//я так понимаю вы сдесь берете элементы первой строки с конца
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {//и зачем-то сравниваете с каждым элементом
        if (arr[i][j] == sbd) {
          m = i + 1;//а это типо сохранение результата чтоли?
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cout << m << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Естественно это не работает так как вы хотели. Почему бы не взять значения, которые вы выбрали для сравнения в массив и сравнивать их построчно?

```
int temp[cols]{};

for (int i = cols - 1, count = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++count) {
  temp[count] = arr[0][i];
}

std::cout << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
  std::cout << temp[i];
}
std::cout << std::endl;

bool solution{true};
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  solution = true;
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
    if (temp[j] != arr[i][j]) {
      solution = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (solution  == true) {
    cout << i << " ";
  }
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял ваш пример, а то, что сравнивать нужно построчно понятно, но не понятно как ))

Comment: @NikolayPshenichnyy если поняли, то почему так не сделали? Что касается примера - что не понятно?